# if every set is an element of some set (axiom of pairing), how come if A is any set and B={x∈A:x∉x}, B∉A?

Tags: set-theory, foundations

I'm reading naïve set theory by Halmos and at page 6, while explaining the axiom of specification (and Russell's paradox) he says:
"whatever the set A may be, if B={x∈A:x∉x} B∈A is impossible"

then at page 10 he says:
The axiom of pairing ensures that every set is an element of some set

so my question is, if every set is an element of some set, how come B={x∈A:x∉x} is not element of A even though A can be any set?

Comment: The definition of $B$ depends on $A$. $B$ is an element of some set, just not the $A$ that was used in its definition.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand.. how can B be an element of some set if A can be ANY set and B∉A still?

Comment: $B\in\{B\}$, $B\notin A$.

Comment: @AndreaBurgio, you have to first choose one specific $A$ before you create $B$. This $B$ is an element of another set, just not the original $A$ you started with.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown but "the axiom of regularity together with the axiom of pairing implies that no set is an element of itself" so such set cannot exist.. right? i'm sorry but all this is pretty confusing

Comment: Every set satisfies $B\in\{B\}$. The axiom of regularity has nothing to do with this.

Comment: You are muddling the statements $\forall A\,\exists B: B\notin A$ (true) with $\exists B\,\forall A: B\notin A$ (false).

Comment: Step 1:  Let $A$ be any set.  Do that. It is done. We have set $A$ to be a set.  It is now set in stone.  It can not change.  Step 2: Define $B$. Step 3: Argue $B\not \in A$. Step 4: Point out there is a set that $B$ *is* a member of. Step 5: Observe that $A$, now that it has been set in stone, can not be that set.  Now that $A$ is set in stone it is *not* the case that $A$ can be any set.  It can not.  It is set in stone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a linguistic trap.

If you say $A$ can be any #thing#, once you specify it, it is no longer arbitrary.  You have now labelled it as a specific #thing# and even though you know nothing about it everything you do with it *now*, is not arbitrary but about $A$

Here's a silly example.  If you say "Let $A$ be any number".  Then we say.  Let $B = A-1$ so $B < A$.  Now suppose we argue "But we said $A$ could be any number.  So $A$ doesn't have to be less than $B$".   So it is perfectly possible, in theory, that there is some number where $A -1 \ge A$.

Do you see the problem there?

You argument is much the same.  Let $A$ be any set.... but once we label it, it is no longer *any* set.  It is $A$; a specific set.  We define $B$ based on $A$ but we can't just change what $A$ is.

....

Analogy.  Suppose we claimed: Every number is larger than some number.  But ten pages later we claim.  Let $B = A-1$.  Then we *must* have $B< A$.

Suppose we argue:  But why is $B < A$?  $B$ is greater than some number and $A$ can be any number, so why can't $A < B$?

Well, because we already *defined* $A$ and *then* we defined $B$.  $A$ *can't* be any number *now*.  It's too late.  It could be any number when we brought it up but *now* it's committed to being $A$.

Answer (score 4):

The point is that there isn't a *single* set $B$: each $A$ determines its own $B_A$. So e.g. we'd have $B_A\not\in A$ but $B_A$ might well be in some other set $C$. Of course $B_C\not\in C$, but so what? $B_A$ and $B_C$ can be different sets (and indeed will have to be if $B_A\in C$).

Comment: but then how can the axiom of specification avoid Russell's paradox?
in set sheory and logic by Stoll, he says:
"the axiom of specification only provides the existence of a set corresponding to a condition and which is a subset of an existing set. With this restrictive feature, Russell's paradox cannot be reconstructed" then he goes ahead proving that if A is any set and B={x∈A:x∉x}, B∉A, so I thought that since B cannot be a member of any set it cannot exist (solving Russell's paradox). But now I'm more confused because all of you are telling me that it can be a member of another set..

Comment: @AndreaBurgio Once again, **there is no single $B$**. It depends on $A$ (notice that $A$ appears in the definition of $B$!). By analogy, think of the statement "For every number $a$ the number $b=a+1$ is not equal to $a$;" does that mean there is a single number not equal to any number? No, of course not.